# How to place vue variable inside a laravel bracket

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am having problem displaying the vue variable output when using it together with laravel. Below is my code.

```
<input type="text" 
               class="form-control search-bar__input" 
               placeholder="Search Courses, Interests, Schools or Institutions" 
               autocomplete="on" 
               autofocus="on"
               v-model="query"
               v-on:keyup="search">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="course in courses">
        <a href="{{ route('courses.show', '{{ course.id }}') }}">@{{ course.title }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the above code I make used of `@{{course.id}}` inside the route in the a element. However it seems it is not working. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're mixing up server side and client side code there. You're passing `@{{course.id}}` as a parameter to a PHP function, so you'll probably be getting a syntax error.

You should use Laravel to output your route and then in your HTML/Blade you can output a Vue variable using the `@{{ }}` syntax.

```
<a href="{{ route('courses.show') }}?course_id=@{{ course.id }}">@{{ course.title }}</a>
```

That will generate a URL like `http://yourdomain.com/courses/path/` and stick `?course_id=` on the end of it.

My guess is that you're trying to use a route with a parameter in it, rather than a query string. In which case, you should try something like this (Not tested):

```
<a href="{{ route('courses.show', '') }}/@{{ course.id }}">@{{ course.title }}</a>
```

Note that I have put quotes `'` around the second parameter to `route` and I have omitted the `@` since we're hoping to directly output `{{ course.id }}` and we're in PHP, not Blade.

With any luck your URL will be generated as something like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/courses/path/{{ course.id }}
```

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you for your answer. Yeah I am using the course.id as parameter. I tried your answer but it gives me error ( syntax error, unexpected '}' ).

Comment: Can you copy and paste your updated code into your question please?

Comment: @Jonathan Please see my updated question. I tried it but giving me syntax error.

Comment: It looks like that's a problem with the Blade compiler. It seems to think the `}}` inside the second parameter is the end of the blade tag. See my updated answer (Second bit of code) for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Jonathan Wow working fine. Why there is a need to include '' in the route?

Comment: @Jearson Great! If your route contains a non-optional parameter e.g. `courses/{id}`, then you need to pass it a value when you use `route()`. If you don't you'll get an error. So the empty string there is just a *dirty* way of passing it a parameter, without actually passing a value through. Then you're able to just add on the parameter you need for Vue.

Comment: @Jonathan Okay got it. Thank you again.