# How to pass a VueJS variable into a Laravel blade route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm looping over a JSON array in VueJS and outputting each item to the screen but I need to create a link/route to a resource controller with the ID being returned for each row like so:

```
<tr v-for="item in searchResults.group">
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.edit', @{{ item.id }} ) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button></a>
```

So I've tried putting the variable into the route like so `@{{ item.id }}` but get the error:

`syntax error, unexpected '{' (View: /application/resources/views/admin/edit.blade.php)`

The way I have done it is not the correct way obviously but I can't find anything in the documentation to achieve this.

---

EDIT:

Further input on this. The route function requires a second parameter, in this case, the ID of the item to edit. In pure PHP/Blade I have this and it works:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $item->id ) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Reduce</button></a>
```

For the dynamic search page, I need to somehow pass that second parameter into blade/php from a vuejs variable but I just can't work out how to do it.

Comment: Can you show route defined in web file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place vue variable inside a laravel bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389995/how-to-place-vue-variable-inside-a-laravel-bracket)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this using backtick.

Its works for me. I hope it's helpful for you.

```
<a :href=`{{ route('admin.edit', '') }}/${item.id}`>
```

Comment: Good answer and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two concepts that won't go together like this.

The blade template is rendered server-side, whereas the parts of your vue.js related markup will be parsed on the client side (e.g. "browser").

Because of that, referencing a property of `item` within a blade expression will fail (as it does).

`<a href="{{ route('admin.edit', @{{ item.id }} ) }}"`

`route(...)` refers to an expression that is related to blade, an `item` is supposed to be a part of your vue.js app.

What you need to do is to dynamically create the link for editing the ressource within your vue.js app once you loop your `searchResult.group`.

You could achieve this by injecting a "route-template" for editing the ressource into your vue.js app and bind the href property to a vue.js method, like this:

```
<tr v-for="item in searchResults.group">
    <a v-bind:href="getEditLink(item.id)">Edit</a>
....
```

The according method `getEditLink(id)` then assembles the actual link based on the given id of `item` and the provided "route"-template.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by appending the id to the end like so:

```
{{ route('admin.edit') }}/@{{ item.id }}
```

I'm guessing you are following a REST URI guides so that would work for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, this doesn't work I tried something similar, it fails because route is expecting a second parameter (the id in this case) `Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.edit] [URI: admin/edit/{id}]`

Comment: @twigg What you could do was to define the route `admin.edit`s parameter optional and then use the method I suggested in my answer. Not the best option but it's the only answer I'm seeing now. Let me know if you need more clarification and I can edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this

```
 <a href="{{ route('admin.edit') }}?course_id=@{{ item.id }}">Click</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, this doesn't work I tried something similar, it fails because route is expecting a second parameter (the id in this case) Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.edit] [URI: admin/edit/{id}]