# Vue varibale inside Laravel helper

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

This is my Laravel route:

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticleController@show')->name('article');
```

This is my blade in Laravel:

```
<a href="{{ route('article', '') }}/@{{ article.id }}">Article</a>
```

I tried this: 
[How to place vue variable inside a laravel bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389995/how-to-place-vue-variable-inside-a-laravel-bracket)

But for me this return:

https://example.xyz/article/%7B%7B%20value.id%20%7D%7D

I need something like that:

```
<a href="{{ route('article', 'article.id') }}">Article</a>
```

Where `article.id` is a Vue variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: `route` works serverside and vue works client side. Sorry to disappoint you but the way to do this is not as simple as you might expect. Personally I pass a stub with a placeholder to my view framework i.e. `route('article', ':id')` and then do a string replace of `:id` with what I need. Based on your particular use case you might also have a better way by making a new component instance per component that will be receiving this `<a>` tag and making the link static for that specific identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. But you can use Ziggy which allows you to use `route()` function in vue like you are using it in laravel.
https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy
Then in your vue component you can call `route('article', {id: article.id})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="{{ route('article', ['id':'article.id']) }}">Article</a>
```